# Sharepoint oracle table integration with BCS or designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'd like to put a table form oracle on my sharepoint 2010 (and soon to be updated 2013) site so that the table can be updated and new rows can be inserted. After googling using BCS seems to be the only option. Is this correct? the Sharepoint designer will not work with Oracle?

Also when I open Visual Studio 2012 Professional and click on new project>>Sharepoint>>Sharepoint 2010 Project I get an error saying

```
Sharepoint server must be installed to workwith share point projects.
```

Do I need to install sharepoint server on my machine?

Can anyone provide any documentation on how to do this?  what happens when I go to Sharepoint 2013?

Oh yea and I have windows 7. Will sharepoint server work on windows 7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer all your questions.

**Oracle connectivity**
BCS supports Oracle but it's not trivial. Sharepoint designer is a tool where you can create External Types (BCS types). But with Sharepoint Designer you are limited to SQL Server, WCF Services and .NET assemblies. There are few workarounds:

- Create linked server to oracle in SQL Serve Management Studio and use Sharepoint Designer to create BCSentities
- You can create service for fetching oracle data and use Sharepoint designer to create BCS entities
- If you just want to display some data from oracle and have developer knowledge. You can use ODAC for .NET and create webparts for displaying data (the simplest solution of all).

For **Sharepoint 2010 Development** you have to install sharepoint (foundation or server) on copmuter where your VS resides. Sharepoint foundation could be installed on Windows 7 x64. Installation is trivial download sharepoint foundation and run installation file.

For **Sharepoint 2013**. You can create apps and client apps on remote computer but for farm solutions there is the same rule (but SP 2013 can't be installed on Windows 7).